# Why does userena.forms.EditProfileForm add 2 extra fields?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using `django-userena` inside a Django 1.5.1 project.

I am implementing the user thing of the website, so basically `django-userena` does it just fine. However I noticed that the `EditProfileForm` contains 2 extra fields:

- First name
- Last name

[image: EditProfileForm]

As in the documentation, I used `userena.models.UserenaBaseProfile` in my own model `accounts.models.Profile`. It inherits `UserenaBaseProfile` as well as `BaseHuman` a class of mine.

From the bottom to the top:

- 1 field from `accounts.models.Profile`
- 2 fields from `userena.models.UserenaBaseProfile`
- 3 fields from `helpers.models.BaseHuman`
- 2 extra fields I know nothing about (from `EditProfileForm` ?)

## Issue

---

So I thougt at first that creating a `EditProfileFormExtra` would overwrite those 2 extra fields, but I cannot even add extra fields like in [the documentation](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-add-extra-fields-to-forms).

Here are my URLs:

```py
# Admin URLs
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/',   include(admin.site.urls)),
)

# Userena URLs
urlpatterns += patterns('userena.views',
    url(r'^^(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/edit/$', 'profile_edit', {'edit_profile_form': EditProfileFormExtra}),
)

# Homemade URLs
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    # ...
)

# Flatpage URLs
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.flatpages.views',
    # ...
)
```

Having followed the documentation and applied it to `userena.views.profile_edit`, I don't see where my mistake(s) could be. I double checked the view, URL, and form names.

## Questions

---

1. Why are there 2 extra fields on the profile form ?
2. I cannot add extra fields to the profile form, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First name and last name fields are sort of baked into the EditProfileForm. Have a look at the form class: https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/forms.py It seems the easiest way you can get rid of these fields is to create your own form class rather than subclassing EditProfileForm.
2. I would need to see a snippet of your form code but there is no reason you can't add additional fields. If you go the route of creating your own form class, add the fields like in the F.A.Q. you linked to and you shouldn't have any issues.